# How to add an introduction image before iPhone application starts?

Tags: iphone, objective-c-2.0

How do you add a static image (.png) as soon as the iPhone application starts before loading the content of the application. In other words, I want an introduction image. I can't figure out the code required to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just create an image and name id Default.png. It appears while the app is loading.

Comment: Great, thank you! How do I set it to delay a few seconds. like 2-3 seconds before it loads the application.

Comment: 1 of 2 ways. 
1. Make your default view controller the exact same image and create an NSTimer to push another view after a few seconds. (the better way of doing it)
2. use sleep(3);  this will pause your app for a few seconds. (not such a good practice, and apple might not like this)

Comment: Apple doesn't care if you call `sleep()` (the user perception is equivalent) and it's cleaner from some perspectives. Just don't sleep for too long (10s?), or I think the OS terminates your app for taking too long to start!